# How to correct an invalid JSON that contains unescaped special characters

Tags: java, spring-boot

#### Context

The data source (DB) returns CLOB data on one of the columns. It's supposed to be a valid JSON and most of the time it is. But in certain cases, it may contain JSON-special characters such as `\` or `"`.

For e.x. sourceJson =

```
{
  "appName": "Sample \ "App " Name"
}
```

#### Questions

Correcting this in the data source is probably the right approach. But if that's infeasible,

1. How to correct an invalid JSON that contains unescaped special characters on the receiver side (Java)?
2. I can handle `\` by doing `String replaced = sourceJson.replace("\\", "\\\\");` but what about `"`?
3. If the only way is to manually replace, are there characters other than `\`, `"` that should be replaced this way?

#### What have I tried so far?

1. Escape the source JSON using `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils` and use that to deserialize

```
String escapeJson = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(sourceJson);
Gson gson = new Gson();

MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(escapeJson, MyObject.class);
// produces com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected name at line 1 column 2 path $.appName=null
```

2. Use `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonStringEncoder.getInstance().quoteAsString` and use that to deserialize

```
String quotedJson = String.valueOf(JsonStringEncoder.getInstance().quoteAsString(sourceJson));

Gson gson = new Gson();
MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(quotedJson, MyObject.class);
// produces com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected name at line 1 column 2 path $.appName=null
```

3. Same as 1 except use ObjectMapper to deserialize

```
String escapeJson = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(sourceJson);

ObjectMapper objectMapper = JsonMapper.builder()
          .enable(JsonReadFeature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER,
              JsonReadFeature.ALLOW_UNESCAPED_CONTROL_CHARS)
          .build();
MyObject obj = objectMapper.readValue(escapeJson, MyObject.class);
// produces Unexpected character ('\' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
```

4. Same as 2 except use ObjectMapper to deserialize

```
String quotedJson = String.valueOf(JsonStringEncoder.getInstance().quoteAsString(sourceJson));

ObjectMapper objectMapper = JsonMapper.builder()
          .enable(JsonReadFeature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER,
              JsonReadFeature.ALLOW_UNESCAPED_CONTROL_CHARS)
          .build();
MyObject obj = objectMapper.readValue(escapeJson, MyObject.class);
// produces Unexpected character ('\' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
```

#### Research Inferences

1. I have looked at several SO posts but they all talk about escaping strings at the source side
2. The only way I can think of making it work on the receiver side is by manually replacing it with some regexes. Replacing a single `\` is easy (probably regex=`\\` should do). But I don't know how to replace a single/unterminated `"` with regex

Comment: In order to fix the input programmatically you need to understand and enumerate the types of errors involved.  It may be that some errors cannot be unambiguously detected, in which case you may be out of luck.  In any event, none of your current approaches will work because you'll need to process the input stream yourself, and fix the errors, _before_ passing it to any "standard" parser.

Comment: To "fix" the problem you'll need to write a non-trivial parser that can detect problems and know how to fix them, which is basically a bad idea because it validates the source of the problem allowing, even encouraging, them to create bad output. IMHO the best approach is to reject invalid input which will force the producer to stop causing problems.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that fixing at the source is the best solution. I'll try for that

Answer (score -1):

I think a regex could be quite complex because there is so much to consider. Specially if the JSON is not available wellformed.

```json
{"appName": "Sample \ "App "  Name", "foo"
: "Bar App \ "Name",
  "test":[{"a": "b"}]}
```

I would format the JSON and then process it line by line. With a RegEx or/and StringMethods you can then repair the values line by line.

```json
{
"appName":"Sample \ "App "  Name",
"foo":"Bar App \ "Name", 
"test":
[
{
"a":"b"
}
]
}
```

**Example / Proof of Concept**

You will have to correct the JSON programmatically because otherwise no JSON parser will be able to process it. The following is a PoC. I would pursue it like this if I had this challenge. I don't know a library that fixes corrupt JSON. The question would be, how does the corrupt JSON get into your database?

```java
String corruptJson = "{\"appName\": \"Sample \\ \"App \"  Name\", \"foo\"\n" +
        ": \"Bar App \\ \"Name\",\n" +
        "  \"test\":[{\"a\": \"b\"}]}";

String replacedJson = corruptJson
        .replaceAll("[\\n\\s]*:[\\n\\s]*", ":")
        .replaceAll("([\\{\\},\\[\\]])", "\n$1\n");

StringBuilder cleanedJson = new StringBuilder();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(replacedJson);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if (line.length() > 0) {
        int posDoublePoint = line.indexOf(":");
        if (posDoublePoint > 0) {
            String key = line.substring(0, posDoublePoint);
            String value = line.substring(posDoublePoint + 1).trim();
            if (value.length() > 0) {
                value = value.replaceAll("^\"", "");
                value = value.replaceAll("\"$", "");
                value = value.replace("\\", "");
                value = value.replace("\"", "\\\"");
                cleanedJson.append(key).append(":").append(String.format("\"%s\"", value));
                continue;
            }
        }
        cleanedJson.append(line);
    }
}
scanner.close();

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String prettyJson = gson.toJson(JsonParser.parseString(cleanedJson.toString()));
```

```json
{
  "appName": "Sample  \"App \"  Name",
  "foo": "Bar App  \"Name",
  "test": [
    {
      "a": "b"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: _"format the JSON"_ -- how (other than manually) would a formatter know what to do with `"appName":"Sample \ "App "  Name",`?

Comment: @JimGarrison I have my answer extended.

Comment: @Bademeister While I have debugged it to understand what's being done and I do understand it to an extent I'll admit that it's doing some magic. I tried this code and it does work, but does it cover all the cases? Also, when I supply `sourceJson` to this code, the `cleanedJson` it produces looks more or less the same as the `sourceJson` except a couple of newlines are added. So, why does it work then?

Comment: BTW I found a way to break this logic. If we supply a properly escaped valid JSON to this logic, it doesn't produce the right result. For e.x. `sourceJson={"appName": "Sample :\\ \"App \" Name"}`. It produces `Sample: "App " Name` but expected is `Sample:\ "App " Name`

Comment: @CyriacGeorge As I wrote, it is a PoC. You have to add any cases yourself. But the best solution is to make sure that wellformed JSON is stored in the database.